# Convert Restangular request to url

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm pretty new to Restangular and am creating some failed requests. Is it possible to somehow see which url get's built by a Restangular request to help me figure out what is wrong.

I would like to translate the request:

```
Restangular.one('organisations', 145).get('organisation');
```

to something like

```
>> www.mysite.com/api/organisations/145/organisation
```

with something like

```
console.log(Restangular.one('organisations', 145).get('organisation').toUrl())
```